# PHP if statement inside for loop and append result in divs

Tags: php, jquery, if-statement, for-loop

Although I have resorted to stackoverflow for answers in the past many times but this is my first ever question on stackoverflow. I researched a lot about my issue and couldnt get answer to this specific issue. Hope posting actual question might help.

So here it is: 
I have 2 divs in artwork.php

echo `'<div id="on_going_art"></div>'`;

echo `'<div id="completed_art"></div>'`;

My DB has 2 tables: artwork and user_hour_log
each user_id can have multiple art_id assigned to it and each art_id can have multiple user_hour_log entries.
Say $art[] is an array with multiple art_id in it and I am getting user_id from cookie:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($art); $i++){

            $query2= "SELECT *, SUM(total_time) AS total_time FROM user_hour_log WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."' && art_id = '".$art[$i]."'";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);

            $row2 = $result2 -> fetch_assoc();
            $hours_completed_artwork = $row2['total_time'];

            $query3= "SELECT * FROM artwork WHERE winner_user_id = '".$user_id."' && art_id = '".$art[$i]."'";
            $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $query3);
            $row3 = $result3 -> fetch_assoc();
            $highest_bid_hours = $row3['highest_bid_hours'];
```

Here I am checking if $hours_completed_artwork is less than $highest_bid_hours, then append in #on_goin_art else append in #completed_art respectively:

```
if($hours_completed_artwork < $highest_bid_hours) {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function() {
                                $("#on_going_art").append("
                                    echo "<div class=\"row box1\">";
                                    echo "<div class=\"col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4\">";
                                    echo "<img class=\"img-responsive thumbnail\" src=\"http://i.imgur.com/jYea7Id.jpg?1\">";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                    echo "<div class=\"col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8\">";
                                    echo "<h6 >"'.$row3['artwork_name'].'"<span id=\"percentage\">"'.number_format($hours_completed_artwork/ $highest_bid_hours *100,0).'"%</span> </h6>";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                    echo "</div>";
                                ");
                            });
                        </script>';
    } else if($hours_completed_artwork >= $highest_bid_hours)  {
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                                $(document).ready(function() {
                                     $("#completed_art").append("
                                        echo "<div class=\"row box1\"> \n";
                                        echo "<div class=\"col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4\"> \n";
                                        echo "<img class=\"img-responsive thumbnail\" src=\"http://i.imgur.com/jYea7Id.jpg?1\"> \n";
                                        echo "</div> \n";
                                        echo "<div class=\"col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8\"> \n";
                                        echo "<h6 >'.$row3['artwork_name'].'<span id=\"percentage\">100% </span> </h6> \n";
                                        echo "</div> \n";
                                        echo "</div>";
                                     ");
                                });
                            </script>';
```

The problem is the append doesnt work, if I append just the strings eg: 'incomplete' and 'complete' it appends perfectly in right divs but it doesnt do it with my code.

I tried closing php tags right before including script tags that dint work either.
I have included Google CDN jquery links, tried changing position of script tags.

Sorry for such a long question. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: convert $row3['artwork_name'] these inside single quotes to double quotes and try again.

Comment: Actually thats not the problem because if I check the DOM it is appending to right divs with the value of $row3['artwork_name'] but its not converting HTML tags. It just appends the same code as is with all the div tags and img tags without parsing them to display. And I get error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" but there is no syntax error at all.

Comment: you are also using echo with each line, remove it, one main echo is enough.

Comment: I did that too, but no help. I also ended php tags just before start of script tags and wrote the code without echo, dint workout either.

Comment: can you please check your browser console and see what error are you getting?

Comment: suggestion to make it easier and less buggy: write the html to a php var as string, then include it to js-code. This way it's just very difficult for you with all the quotes and escaped quotes, ...

Comment: because right now you have loads of js syntax errors.

Comment: Your implementation looks weird to me. if you have access to artwork.php you can simply do `echo '<div id="on_going_art">'.$stuffgoeshere.'</div>';` with `$stuffgoeshere` being a string constructed from all entries matching `if($hours_completed_artwork < $highest_bid_hours)` without needing any inserted javascript like that. Also, the quotes seem badly formatted. After `.append("` you might want to concatenate subsequent strings instead of calling these confusing echo's.

Comment: Or use HEREDOC! Such things are much easier with [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: Please see/try my answer @NitinRaghav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working snippet:

```
$row3['artwork_name'] = 'Some name';
$hours_completed_artwork = 40;
$highest_bid_hours = 50.00;

$percentage = $hours_completed_artwork < $highest_bid_hours ? number_format($hours_completed_artwork/ $highest_bid_hours *100,0) : 100;
$html = '<div class="row box1">\'+
         \'<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">\'+
         \'<img class="img-responsive thumbnail" src="http://i.imgur.com/jYea7Id.jpg?1">\'+
         \'</div>\'+
         \'<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8">\'+
         \'<h6 >'.$row3['artwork_name'].'<span id="percentage">'.$percentage.'%</span> </h6>\'+
         \'</div>\'+
         \'</div>';


$snippet = '<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#on_going_art").append(\''.$html.'\');
});
</script>';

echo '<div id="on_going_art"></div>';
echo $snippet;
```

I refactored the code to make it more maintainable. In javascript you cannot just throw html into an append function. New lines need to be concatenated using + and single or quotes. That is built in now. Also since only the percentage is either 100 or variable, i put that lot into one variable.

Comment: Thank you so much this code works just fine. What I understood from your solution is that I was writing script in PHP but never called it like you did with "echo $snippet;" and when I introduced that part in my code it worked fine off-course with some refactoring done to my append string.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies. Too bad I cant rate anybody good just now coz of less than 15 reputations.

Comment: Just echoing the html elements with new lines (the part that went wrong mostly), would produce an error in javascript moaning about unexpected token or similar. Because in the resulting and displayed javascript the quotes were missing in the append() function and new lines always have to be concatenated using single or double quotes. E.g. "<p>string line1</p>" + "<p>string line 2</p>"

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are messed up.
And you have multiple echos inside the string, I guess you just copied the code and put it into the string.

It would be easier to build the html first, put it into a var, then use it:

```
if($hours_completed_artwork < $highest_bid_hours) {
    $html = "<div class=\"row box1\">
             <div class=\"col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4\">
             <img class=\"img-responsive thumbnail\" src=\"http://i.imgur.com/jYea7Id.jpg?1\">
                                </div>
                                <div class=\"col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8\">
                                <h6 >".$row3['artwork_name']."<span id=\"percentage\">".number_format($hours_completed_artwork/ $highest_bid_hours *100,0)."%</span> </h6>
                   </div>
                   </div>";

    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
          $(document).ready(function() {
               $(\"#on_going_art\").append('".$html."');
          });
         </script>";

//....
```

Even better would be the use of [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) or NEWDOC

Anyway the structure seems a little odd to me. Why don't you include the html via php in first place? Does it really have to be added later via javascript?